# React Native - Keyboard covers bottom part of the input

Tags: javascript, react-native, keyboard

In my app keyboard covers only bottom part of the text input. I have tried several ways to solve this by changing styles by adding padding or margin, and also KeyboardAvoidingView didn't help.

Another problem is that keyboard shifts the whole screen and header becomes invisible as it goes above.

**Edit:** It works fine on IOS devices.

How can I fix these problems?
Thanks

Code:

```
<>
           <CustomHeader title={item.title}
                         leftChild={<SvgImageComp name={MENU_ICON}/>}
                         centerChild={
                             <TextComp text={'Title'} style={compStyle.title}/>
                         }
           />
           <View style={{
               flex: 1,
               justifyContent: 'flex-end'
           }}>
               <KeyboardAvoidingView
                   behavior={"height"}
               >
               <TextInputComp fontFamily={NUNITO_SANS_REGULAR}
                              fontSize={15}
                              lineHeight={20}
                              autoFocus={true}
                              style={{
                                  paddingVertical: 10,
                                  paddingHorizontal: 20,
                                  borderWidth: 1,
                                  borderColor: '#000',
                                  borderRadius: 200,
                              }}
               />
               </KeyboardAvoidingView>
           </View>
       </>
```

[image]

Comment: Quick comment: I have added "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan" to app.json file. Without that, the header does not move, but keyboard shifts bottom bar above.

Answer (score 1):

For Android you don't need to pass behavior to KeyboardAvoidingView. For IOS you need to pass  behavior="position" and keyboardVerticalOffset=[height of your input].

```
 <KeyboardAvoidingView
          {...(Platform.OS === 'ios'
            ? {
                behavior: 'position' ,
                keyboardVerticalOffset: [inputHeight], // calculate height using onLayout callback method
              }
            : {})}>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried it with a bottom navigation bar? Because without bottom navigation bar, it works normally.

Answer (score -1):

I avoid this issue by wrapping the screen in `<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={flexGrow: 1}><ScrollView>` This will make the whole screen turn into a scroll view once the keyboard opens. Allowing the box to be out of the way of the keyboard. This also has the added benefit of allowing you to scroll to other sections of the screen for reference while the keyboard stays open.